# Calling a smart contract function using metamask with ether.js

Tags: javascript, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js, ethers.js

I'm completely new to both blockchain and JavaScript.

I'm trying to create a simple web page where people could generate a "wedding" smart contract that basically store their 2 names. For this I have created a WeddingCerficate contract which store the names and have a getter function, and a WeddingCertificateFactory That enable me to generate a WeddingCertificate. You can find the code of the smart contracts in solidity below.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract WeddingCertificate{
  string private spouse1;
  string private spouse2;

  constructor(string memory _spouse1, string memory _spouse2) {
      spouse1 = _spouse1;
      spouse2 = _spouse2;
  }

  function getSpouses() public view returns (string memory,string memory) {
  return (spouse1,spouse2);
  } 

}

contract WeddingCertificateFactory{


   event Wedding(string _spouse1, string _spouse2, address indexed contract_adress );

   function Unite(string memory _spouse1, string memory _spouse2)public returns (bool success) {
           WeddingCertificate wedding = new WeddingCertificate(_spouse1, _spouse2);
           emit Wedding(_spouse1,_spouse2 , address(wedding));
           return true ;

   }


}
```

I deployed the WeddingCertificateFactory on Goerli Tesnet. And now I'm trying to make a function in javascript (using ether.js) to enable a user to create his own weddingCertificate directly on a web interface.

For this I wrote the function below but for some reasons this only generates the new Wedding certificate once out 20. And even when it actually work, the two last print aren't visible in the console.

I do not get any error (at least that I can see in the console) when I test the function and nothing happen.

I'm not familiar with async in JavaScript, I also tried the `.then(` syntax but I didn't notice any difference.

```
async function CreateWedding(){
    const spouse1 = document.getElementById("spouse1").value;
    const spouse2 = document.getElementById("spouse2").value;
    if (spouse1.length > 0 && spouse2.length >0) {
      console.log(`spouse 1: ${spouse1} , spouse2 : ${spouse2} `);

      const ethereum = window.ethereum ;
      const accounts = await ethereum.request({
      method: "eth_requestAccounts",
      });

      const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum, "any");
      const walletAddress = accounts[0];
      const signer = provider.getSigner(walletAddress);

      let abi = [
          " function Unite(string memory _spouse1, string memory _spouse2)"
      ];


      const contractAddress = "0x2556Ff7f7F1c013bBB60bD120E1828032Cd84cc4"; //WeddingFactory Contract

      const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, signer);

      console.log("sending the contract");

      tx = await contract.Unite(spouse1,spouse2);
      console.log(tx);
      console.log("finished");



    } else {
        alert("Please enter 2 names");
    }

  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try creating your abi method in [web3client.app](https://workspace.web3client.app/evm?web3ClientToken=50f4540e-e813-48a0-8cac-e2bd762a86ea).

It has code generater for ether.js which yoy can use directly in your app.

If there is an actual issue in your contract it would fail there itself.